# How to show a datepicker after pressing a TableView cell swipe edit action

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, datepicker

I want to show a `datepicker` after pressing a `tableview swipe edit action button`. It is called postpone, and after opening a datepicker, I want my user to choose a date and press done button of datepicker's toolbar. I've created the `datepicker` and `toolbar` but I don't know how to show it with the edit action.

**Here is the datepicker code :**

```
func createDatePicker() {
    picker.datePickerMode = .date

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolbar.isTranslucent = true
    toolbar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 189/255, green: 194/255, blue: 201/255, alpha: 1)
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePicker))
    doneButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelPicker))
    cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.black

    toolbar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    //dateTimeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar (I was using this part to open a datepicker with a text field but I don't know how to modify it for the edit action)
    //dateTimeTextField.inputView = picker
    picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

**The edit action code :**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{
    let postpone = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Postpone"){(UITableViewRowAction,NSIndexPath) -> Void in
        self.tasks[indexPath.row].status = "postpone"
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.tasks)
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "taskList")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "taskList")
        self.taskTableView.reloadData()
    }
    postpone.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 222/255, green: 119/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1)

    return [done, cancel, postpone]
}
```

**Edit Action buttons image:**

[image: Edit Action buttons]

**Datepicker image in a different page :**

[image: Datepicker]

> Update ~ After I added this code

```
picker.addSubview(toolbar)
    taskTableView.addSubview(picker)
    taskTableView.bringSubview(toFront: picker)
```

[image: Datepicker]

Comment: You need open your view in the pospone action inside your `editActionsForRowAt` action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the datePicker adding it to your view:

```
func createDatePicker() {
    picker.datePickerMode = .date

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolbar.isTranslucent = true
    toolbar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 189/255, green: 194/255, blue: 201/255, alpha: 1)
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePicker))
    doneButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelPicker))
    cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.black

    toolbar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    //add the picker to your view or tableView if you use UITableViewController
    taskTableView.addSubview(picker)
    taskTableView.bringSubview(toFront: picker)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let postpone = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Postpone"){(UITableViewRowAction,NSIndexPath) -> Void in
        self.tasks[indexPath.row].status = "postpone"
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.tasks)
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "taskList")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "taskList")
        self.taskTableView.reloadData()

        //show your date picker
        self.createDatePicker()

    }
    postpone.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 222/255, green: 119/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1)

    return [done, cancel, postpone]
}
```

To remove the picker call: `picker.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: I added a new ss of the datepicker. I want it to stay at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You can set your picker frame in this way: `picker.frame = CGrect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - 260, width: view.frame.width, height: 260)` 
260 is the height of your picker (216) + the toolbar height (44)